# How to write out n*n Matrix values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, so I decided to try to make a simple n*n Array. When I'm trying to write it out, I get, something starnge back.

```js
var map = [

  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],

  [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],

  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],

  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],

  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],

  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],

  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],

  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],

  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1],

  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
];

function GoTh() {
  for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {
      console.log(map[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
GoTh();
```

I expected it to write all 100 values, but it gives back this:
1 2 3 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 3 1

Comment: It writes all 100 on my screen. Whats your testing environment?

Comment: Your code functions perfectly okay.

Comment: Look at the results in the browser console, not the snippet console, which drops some of the leading logs. Works as expected for me too

Comment: I wrote it in notepad++.
Have a HTML file, and a js file.
The code above is in the js, and I call it in the html.
Using Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because same-value `console.log`s are grouped together in browsers' consoles.

[image]

This can usually be disabled, i.e. in Chrome & Opera:

[image]

In Firefox it's in console's settings (press F1 while using console)

Another option is to write more data along with the value, eg.:

```
      console.log(i, j, map[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the ouput in the console itself. If there are multiple similar entries - like the first 10 elements of value **1** in the first row plus the **1** in the second row, it will be grouped as a single entry of **11**. You can see that there are multiple if you look to the right of a particular entry.

[image]